# SQL Server session stays open when application is closed

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Whenever I shutdown my application, I dispose my `DbContext` object to make sure no connections are alive.

When I run `sp_who` in SQL Server Management Studio, but for some reason the session is still there with `status = 'sleeping'`.

Because of that I can't execute certain commands (ex. `DROP DATABASE`) unless I kill the session, which requires me to find the ID and kill it manually.

Is there a way to kill this session instantly whenever my application closes?

Comment: What kind of application?

Comment: If you need to execute commands that don't tolerate other users, `ALTER DATABASE DBName SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` is your friend (but not the friend of anyone else who had a connection)

Comment: Connections are managed by the Entity Framework, I just use the context which I thought also closed the connection when disposed. This is purely for testing purposes, I don't think the actual application will experience problems from this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity framework uses the underlying SQL Server ADO.NET provider which pools database connections as they are an expensive operation to create and flush each time.

You can flush the connection pool using a [SqlConnection.ClearPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearpool.aspx) method call on your `Application_End` event handler.

**Note:** I would not recommend disabling or flushing the connection pool for production code. An alternate method for development can be to modify to disable pooling via you connection string using the `Pooling=false` option.

Comment: I guess I'll just stick to killing the session manually then since I only need to do this occasionally for testing purposes, I just thought this was some kind of bug. Anyways thanks for the answer!